# dependent events vs sample probability questions

Tags: probability, statistics

Part 1) which of the following examples are dependent events?
A)Rolling a die and spinning a spinner
B) Tossing a coin two times
C) Picking two cards from a deck with replacement of the first card
D) Randomly selecting two students,one at a time,to leave early from class

Part 2) A sample of 1000 dogs was studied.Which of the following simulations would be the best to use to predict the number of male or female dogs in a sample?
A)Rolling a die
B) Tossing a coin
C) Drawing a card from a standard deck of cards
D) Spinning a spinner divided into three equal sectors labelled 1 to 3

my work:

for part 1) first we need to know what a dependent event is?, Two events are dependent if the outcome of the first event affects the outcome of the second event, so that the probability is changed. so the answer is:D-(Randomly selecting two students,one at a time,to leave early from class) because one student leaving affects the second student from leaving,so the probability changes.

for part 2) first we need to know what a sample is ,In probability theory, the sample space (also called sample description space or possibility space) of an experiment or random trial is the set of all possible outcomes or results of that experiment. so the answer is B-(Tossing a coin) because There are two sexes, male and female, and we assume they are of approximately equal likelihood.

.

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Dependence/independence is fully controlled by event algebra(sigma-algebra) i.e. probability triple. Which one, from many possibilities, you bring is not mathematical question. After choose/create model all answers will be predestined.

Comment: @zkutch that doesnt really answer my question but ok ,and you saying that this is not a mathematical expression,well the answer to that is these are scenarios of dependent independent,or sample spacing in probability,and im a grade 12 student,so these are the questions wer are given